# MacOS 10.14.2 control-shift-f doesn't work on IntelliJ and Pycharm

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, pycharm

I use XWin keymap profile on IntelliJ and Pycharm, but I can not activate "Find in path" dialog with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but I can activate "Replace in path" with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this issue: I installed an input method software (Sogou Pinyin), it registered <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> as a shortcut of switching Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese, but even when I use system default input method (ABC), this shortcut is still hijacked, I think that's not a good practice. After I disabled this shortcut in Sogou Pinyin, I can activate "Find in path" by <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

I think there should be an application in MacOS which I can query any shortcuts and its registers, but I can't find it.